# jquery can I run a click event in the page when I reload the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can make the function `click` run everytime after the user reload the page?

what I trying to do is: make the `alert( "Handler for .click() called." );` runs before the user click,

html:

```
<p>First Paragraph</p>
```

jquery:

```
$( "p" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() after reload was called." );
});
```

Comment: trigger click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using `click()` method:

```
$( "p" ).click();
```

Another method is to use `.trigger()` method.

```js
$( "p" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() after reload was called." );
}).trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>First Paragraph</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple..

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#id-of-button-want-to-click-on-reload").trigger('click');
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to trigger the click event for paragraph for this Like

```
$("p").click();
```

Answer (score 1):

As a different approach to firing `click()` listener after pageload you might create a function;

```
var clickHandler = function() {
      alert( "Handler for .click() after reload was called." );
    }
```

And Use it for both click and document.ready listeners

```
$(document).ready(clickHandler);
$( "p" ).click(clickHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is trigger p's click event when the document loads through the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("p").click();
});
```

Its as simple as that.